# Mapbox SDK v10 Filter Layer with Swift

Tags: swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios, mapbox-studio

i working on map project with swift . i created a dataset,tileset and style on studio and its working perfectly fine right now. ı need to add some filters on map so i create 2 layer for ac and dc. but i couldnt change layers with button. i tried this.

func showACStationLayer() {
guard let style = mapView.style else { return }

```
    // Hide DC Station layer
    if let dcStationLayer = style.layer(withIdentifier: dcStationLayerIdentifier) {
        dcStationLayer.isVisible = false
    }

    // Show AC Station layer
    if let acStationLayer = style.layer(withIdentifier: acStationLayerIdentifier) {
        acStationLayer.isVisible = true
    } else {
        let acStationSource = VectorSource(identifier: "acStationSource", configuration: ["url": "your-source-url"])
        let acStationLayer = FillLayer(identifier: acStationLayerIdentifier, source: acStationSource)
        acStationLayer.fillColor = .red
        style.addLayer(acStationLayer)
    }
}
```

but there are some problems. idk can i explain my problem.

Or how can i filter my layer with button? Thank you so much[image: mapboxStudioLayers]

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `mapView.mapboxMap.style.updateLayer(withId:type:update:)` to update layer properties. The direct assignment has no effect.
Take a look at the official sample code [`ShowHideLayerExample`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios/blob/main/Apps/Examples/Examples/All%20Examples/ShowHideLayerExample.swift).

To filter POIs source data you have to set `Layer.filter` expression. Here is the sample that filters data by `class` property:

```swift
func filterPOILayer(for types: [String]) throws {
    try mapView.mapboxMap.style.updateLayer(withId: "poi-label", type: SymbolLayer.self) { layer in
        layer.filter = Exp(.match) {
            Expression(operator: .get, arguments: [.string("class")])
            types
            true
            false
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend you to test expressions in the [Mapbox Studio](https://studio.mapbox.com) first. There you also can learn what types and classes of POIs are exist. For example, to show only Food POIs there is a `food_and_drink` class.

Comment: Actually i tried this example after that post, but not quite right  for my use case. then a little search  i find the "Expressions" but documentation is not very clear for a beginner or just me, do you have any experience with them?

Comment: @Observer23 I'm one of the Maps SDK developers. 
Almost every field of any Layer subtype accept constant value or Expression. Expression is the runtime function that evaluates value based on some factors.
What result you are trying to archive?

Comment: how can i create filter button for my custom dataset and style. M data includes like, type: cafe, type: restaurant. I want a button which displays pins on map which conditions is type==dc only. For swift mapbox v10

Comment: @Observer23 Added a show case to filter POI data on the map.